# Get all post media images via WP REST API

Tags: images, rest-api, json

We want to build a back-end for a mobile app using WordPress. We are trying to get all post images, but when we call https://api.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=58 we are getting only the first image embedded (uploaded via "Media") into post.

How to get all images?

Comment: If an image isn't 'attached' to a post, in which case *Uploaded To* would not set when viewing the image in the media library, then the only way you'll get the images is by parsing the post content HTML.

Comment: There should exist a method for extending the api for getting this

Comment: you can't assume an image in a post is "attached" to it, attachments can only have a single parent, but nothing stops them being used in multiple posts. If you create a post then use an image in it that's already attached to something it won't show in your API query with `parent`, because it has a different parent. The only reliable way is to grab the posts content then try to reverse lookup all the images found inside its content and fields, and to fix any bugs you might have where images do not have post parents assigned. Additionally, attachments can have post parents even if they're unused